# Video not playing after ffmpeg vintage effect is applied

Tags: android, filter, ffmpeg, effect

I am using ffmpeg 3.3.4 for android. I am executing below simple command:

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf curves=vintage -c:a aac ouput.mp4
```

and

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf curves=vintage -c:a copy ouput.mp4
```

The resultant video is not playing in android default video player and Exoplayer as well. I tried on windows using windows media player, it only plays sound but no video. Although VLC media player is playing it properly on android and windows. Any idea whats missing in the above command?

Output video metadata:
https://www.metadata2go.com/result/e9f9b7db-0a91-4148-9073-1a1162f0c7f0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer. The `curves` filter converts the input to RGB coding but most video players require a specific YUV scheme. So I added `yuv420p` as output format.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf curves=vintage,format=yuv420p -c:a copy ouput.mp4
```